# Страд. причастие прош. времени от "ненавидеть"

Tags: причастия, морфология

Какое **страдательное** причастие **прошедшего** времени будет от глагола *ненавидеть*? (пример: *слышать* - *слышанный*, *видеть* - *виденный*) В настоящем времени это будет *ненавидимый*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет такого причастия. Но есть способы выражения требуемой конструкции лексически или "по контексту".

Но обо всем по порядку.

Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени регулярно отсутствуют у *приставочных глаголов несовершенного вида* (кроме весьма спорных типа *разливанный*). Они и у бесприставочных-то не у всех есть. А те что есть, по сути своей очень близки к отглагольным прилагательным.

Обычно вместо страдательного используется возвратная форма причастия действительного (*убивать-убивавшийся, поливать-поливавшийся, заедать-заедавшийся*) но в нашем случае - *"ненавидевшийся"* не является нормативным.

Тут еще надо отметить, что рассматриваются глагольные корни (смотреть, видеть, дышать) особой группы действий, не позволяющие образовывать от своих приставочных форм  вторичного имперфектива на -ыва/-ова (по образцу бить-убить-убивать, рвать-разорвать-разрывать), которые обычно и не содержат в себе семантики, требующей страдательного причастия прошедшего времени от своих приставочных форм. Просто все нужные значения покрываются причастиями от исходной, бесприставочной формы. "Ненавидеть" в этом смысле исключение, поскольку оно наполнено смыслом, не вытекающим прямо их семантики исходного "видеть". Но грамматические законы оказались сильнее, потому требуемые причастия так и не образовались.

В таком случае ничего не остаётся, как использовать лексические формы выражения прошедшего времени: ***ненавидимый [тогда-то и тогда-то] в прошлом***.

Answer (score 2):

Такого причастия нет, так как страдательные причастия прошедшего времени образуются от переходных глаголов совершенного вида, а ненавидеть - глагол несовершенного вида.

А вот причастие "возненавиденный" (от возненавидеть - сов. вид) существует, например: возненавиденное с детства слово.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласна с комментарием, утверждающим возможность образования страдательных причастий прошедшего времени только от переходных глаголов совершенного вида, хотя есть и некоторые исключения: читать - читанный,  делать - деланная улыбка, мерить - меренная ткань, но немереный отрез ткани (отглагольное прилагательное). Я вижу в этом случае изумительную  тонкость русского языка, выражающего саму  "суть" глагола.